# object has no attribute '_compile_metrics', even with metric = ['accuracy']

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I created this structure with the ResNet50 base model and a couple other layers, then compiled it in the end which I made sure I included this small code...

```
metrics=['accuracy']
```

so I should not be having this error, right? What would be the problem then?
This is the code I used to create the CNN architecture.

```
base_model = ResNet50(weights = None, include_top=False, input_shape=(im_size1, im_size2, 3))

x = base_model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(num_class, activation='softmax')(x)

# The model to be trained
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='sgd', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

callbacks_list = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', verbose=1)]
model.summary()
```

Comment: What is the version of your `keras` library? Is it up to date?

Comment: @RezaBehzadpour I just updated keras library to 2.4.3 but i'm still getting the error :(

Answer (score 0):

After modifying `keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping` to `tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping` in the callback, I am able to execute the code without any issue.

Please refer working code in below

```
import tensorflow as tf
#print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model

im_size1=150
im_size2=150
num_class=2

base_model = ResNet50(weights = None, include_top=False, input_shape=(im_size1, im_size2, 3))

x = base_model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(num_class, activation='softmax')(x)

# The model to be trained
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='sgd', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

callbacks_list = [tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', verbose=1)]
model.summary()
```